# location.assign not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I wrote a small jquery code to redirect to google.com after 2 seconds on pressing a button. The code works fine in Firefox, google chrome but not in the Internet Explorer.

I believe the location.assign function is not working since it is the one that is supposed to redirect to another url and all other functions like alert are working but not this one.

The code is as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".prize_select").click(function(){
                var timer = setInterval(redirect,2000);
                function redirect()
                {
                    location.assign("http://www.google.com");
                    timer = clearTimeout(timer);
                }
            });
        });
  </script>
```

I would also say that I have already tried these function:

location.assign
window.location
window.location.href

but none of them seems to work in Internet Explorer

Comment: Have you checked the console for potential errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.  Also, you need `location.href`, not just `window.location`.  This script says, "When `.prize_select` is clicked, redirect to "cnn.com" after 2000 ms.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".prize_select").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com';
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="prize_select">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: This is just as bad as using `eval` because it evalutes javascript code at runtime. I would not encourage it.

Comment: Is this better, @Yogu.

Comment: Yes, that's better, and now you have the function again ;-) But I can't imagine how this would work when the original code did not, even though it's better and more clear.

Comment: Well, he needed `location.href`, not just location :-)

Comment: He used [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.assign) which should work as well, and he mentioned that he tried `location.href`.

Comment: tried all the methods given by you and others's as well but still the same issue. Still not working in IE

Comment: @InzamamTahir, keep in mind that the `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` functions do not work in IE9 and earlier.

Comment: yes, when I open this stackoverflow link in IE then the snippet works

Comment: Then your problem is not in the code that you posted.  The problem would be found elsewhere.  Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Actually, I have got a complete HTML file with some css files. This is a task given by a client. I wanted to ask if you have "explicitly" made an html file and ran it on IE (not the snippet but an actual HTML file) because if it worked on your end then, I have definitely got error somewhere else in the file I have

Comment: Do you maybe need to use vanilla JS?

Comment: Did you load jQuery into your HTML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66608/discussion-between-god-is-good-and-inzamam-tahir).

Comment: The code was right but the problem was found to be in my Internet Explorer settings. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function before using it. e.g.

```
  var timer;      
  var redirect = function(timer) {
    location.assign("http://www.google.com");
    timer = clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  timer = setInterval(function() { redirect(timer); }, 2000);
```

**Update**: now passes `timer` instance

Comment: That should not be the problem, function declarations (those without `var`) are evaluated first.

Comment: @Yogu This depends on the scope at which the script runs.  Within an object definition, you are correct, but I do not believe this is the case for function-scoped script.

Comment: It's called [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) and has nothing to do with objects. I don't think IE handles this differently.